# MySQL storing an index in memory (for reads)

Tags: mysql

I have a large myisam table with 177 million rows, and 2.7gb of index data (2.1gb of data itself). this information is read-only, never updated or deleted. i want to store the index in memory for faster queries (this is for searching).

i know one of my options is memory table. another memcacheddb, which i have never used. what other solutions are out there?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `MyISAM` storage engine doesn't have that functionality itself.
You will need a different storage engine like `MEMORY.` That's the only way for solving the issue in *MySQL*.